# R heatmap2 legend is not correctly displayed. Displays more than asked

Tags: r, heatmap

I am having trouble in this R script.
I am trying visualize heatmap using heatmap.2 function.
I have 2 problems,
one is about the legend.
i have changed the legend scale like so.

```
one_data.min<-min(one_data[one_data!=-15.0719929427],na.rm=TRUE)
one_data.max<-max(one_data, na.rm =TRUE)
pairs.breaks <-c(-15.0719929427, seq(one_data.min, one_data.max,length.out =1000))
gradient1 = colorpanel(sum(pairs.breaks[-1]<=one_data.min),"chartreuse2","white")
gradient2 = colorpanel(sum(pairs.breaks[-1]>one_data.min),"gold" ,"red","red4")
hm.colors = c(gradient1,gradient2)

heatmap.2(one_data,breaks=pairs.breaks, colCol =cols,Rowv = NA,Colv = NA,lhei = c(1,7),offsetRow=0.1,lwid=c(1,5),trace = "none",density.info = "none",col=hm.colors,cexRow = 1.5,cexCol = 1.5,margins=c(9,20))
```

This way I can have a different color for what I don't have.
Heatmap comes out fine, but the legends are shown as below.
[It's suppose to show until -8 but I get a lot more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUtHn.png)

How can I change this?

Two.
I get this error, but still get the heatmap. Can I just ignore?

Error in heatmap.2(one_data, breaks = pairs.breaks, colCol = cols, Rowv = NA,  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In heatmap.2(one_data, breaks = pairs.breaks, colCol = cols, Rowv = NA,  :
  Discrepancy: Rowv is FALSE, while dendrogram is `both'. Omitting row dendogram.
2: In heatmap.2(one_data, breaks = pairs.breaks, colCol = cols, Rowv = NA,  :
  Discrepancy: Colv is FALSE, while dendrogram is`column'. Omitting column dendogram.

Thank you in advance.